# Calculate cumulative sum by row, skipping zeros, and restarting using column names pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

I have a function **to calculate the cumulative sum of the row, restarting the process every time after the Y3 in the column name**.

There should be a sum consisting of *Y1* in the first cell, *Y1+Y2* in the second cell, *Y1+Y2+Y3* in the third cell. Then the code restarts - starting from Y1.

*All the column names have a pattern - they start from Y1, Y2, or Y3.*

I would like to jump over the cells that contain zeros and continue calculating. That is, **if the cell equals zero, it should stay as it is, instead of being overwritten** by the cumulative. The code would skip a *0* cell and add the value of the current cell to the value of the previous, non-zero one.

For instance, *if Y2=0*, the sum in the Y3 cell should be Y3=Y3 (+Y2)+Y1, as usual, while cell *Y2=0* remains unchanged instead of being overwritten by the cumulative *Y2=Y2+Y1*.

I wrote a function (see below), but there are two *issues with the `Rating` *3C* line*.

**Here is the reproducible code chunk:**

```
df=structure(list(Ratingstufe = c("10", "1A", "1B", "2A", "2B", 
     "3A", "3C", "9C"), 
     Y1.Base = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
     Y2.Base = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1), 
     Y3.Base = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
     Y1.Scenario_1 = c(0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1), 
     Y2.Scenario_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1), 
     Y3.Scenario_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0), 
     # Y1.Scenario_2 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
     # Y2.Scenario_2 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
     # Y3.Scenario_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0),
     Y1.Scenario_3 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
     Y2.Scenario_3 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, -1),
     Y3.Scenario_3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)),
     row.names = c(NA,  8L), class = "data.frame")
```

**This is what I tried**.

```
# Function to calculate cumulative sum by row, ignoring zeros and restarting at "Y1"
cumsum_ignore_zeros <- function(row) {
  # Initialize variables
  cumulative <- 0
  result <- numeric(length(row))

  # Iterate through the row elements
  for (i in seq_along(row)) {
    if (row[i] != 0) {
      cumulative <- cumulative + row[i]
      result[i] <- cumulative
    } else {
      result[i] <- row[i]
    }

    # Check if the column name contains 'Y1' and reset cumulative sum if it does
    if (grepl("Y1", names(df)[i])) {
      cumulative <- 0
    }
  }
  return(result)
}

# Apply the function to each row
df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, cumsum_ignore_zeros))
```

***Problem 1***: column **Y3.Scenario_1**. There is an incorrectly calculated *-1* at the **intersection** with the `Rating` *3C*. I feel it's because in the preceding cell (Y2.Scenario_1), there is a result of *0*, and the **function does not add Y3 to Y1, but simply writes Y3 result down**. Instead of jumping over Y2, and then doing **Y3=Y3+Y1**, it seemingly restarts, going *Y3=Y3* instead.

Once *1* was added to *-1* *(Y2=Y2+Y1=1+(-1)=0)* and replaced the cell on the **intersection** of `Rating` *3C* and **Y2.Scenario_1** with *0*, the function ignored *0* in Y2 and restarted? And showed a *Y3=-1*, seemingly a result of summing the *Y3=Y3* (the cell with itself), instead of summing **Y3=Y3+Y1**.

***Problem 2***: The next case where this issue is manifesting itself is when somehow, I believe, *Y1.Scenario_3* adds the value of *Y3.Scenario_1* to itself, when it is not supposed to. Such that **Y1**.Scenario_**3**=**Y1**.Scenario_**3**+**Y3**.Scenario_**1**. It should have been just **Y1**.Scenario_**3**=**Y1**.Scenario_**3**.

Instead, *1* adds *-1* to itself in the on the **intersection** of `Rating` *3C* and **Y1.Scenario_3**, becoming *0*.

*Y1.Scenario_3* was supposed to not look back to *Y3.Scenario_1*. I do not see any other option as to why the result would be like this.

**Here is the outcome I have currently.**

```
tail(df)
  Ratingstufe Y1.Base Y2.Base Y3.Base Y1.Scenario_1 Y2.Scenario_1 Y3.Scenario_1 Y1.Scenario_3 Y2.Scenario_3 Y3.Scenario_3
3          1B       0       0       0             2             0             0             1             2             0
4          2A       0       0       0             2             0             0             1             2             0
5          2B       0       0       0             2             0             0             0             1             0
6          3A       0       0       0             2             0             0             1             3             0
7          3C       0       0       0             2             0            -1             0             2             1
8          9C       1       0       0             1             0             0             1             0             1
```

**And this is what I would like to achieve (I marked the changes by the stars):**

```
tail(df)
  Ratingstufe Y1.Base Y2.Base Y3.Base Y1.Scenario_1 Y2.Scenario_1 Y3.Scenario_1 Y1.Scenario_3 Y2.Scenario_3 Y3.Scenario_3
3          1B       0       0       0             2             0             0             1             2             0
4          2A       0       0       0             2             0             0             1             2             0
5          2B       0       0       0             2             0             0             0             1             0
6          3A       0       0       0             2             0             0             1             3             0
7          3C       0       0       0             2             0             1*            1*            3*            4*
8          9C       1       0       0             1             0             0             1             0             1
```

**My original dataset for your convenience (`dput` can be found above):**

```
tail(df)
  Ratingstufe Y1.Base Y2.Base Y3.Base Y1.Scenario_1 Y2.Scenario_1 Y3.Scenario_1 Y1.Scenario_3 Y2.Scenario_3 Y3.Scenario_3
3          1B       0       0       0             2             0             0             1             1             0
4          2A       0       0       0             2             0             0             1             1             0
5          2B       0       0       0             2             0             0             0             1             0
6          3A       0       0       0             2             0             0             1             2             0
7          3C       0       0       0             2             0            -1             1             2             1
8          9C       1      -1       0             1            -1             0             1            -1             1
```

Any other solution besides correcting the loop is also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can convert the data to long format and get the `cumsum` (with an additional condition) for each "scenario" and "rating" (assuming that ratings are unique), and then convert back to wide format.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Ratingstufe) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c("Y", "Scen"), sep = "\\.", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(csum = cumsum(value) * (value != 0), 
            .by = c(Ratingstufe, Scen)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Ratingstufe, names_from = name, values_from = csum)

#> # A tibble: 8 × 10
#>   Ratingstufe Y1.Base Y2.Base Y3.Base Y1.Scenario_1 Y2.Scenario_1 Y3.Scenario_1
#>   <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1 10                0       0       0             0             0             0
#> 2 1A                0       0       0             0             0             0
#> 3 1B                0       0       0             2             0             0
#> 4 2A                0       0       0             2             0             0
#> 5 2B                0       0       0             2             0             0
#> 6 3A                0       0       0             2             0             0
#> 7 3C                0       0       0             2             0             1
#> 8 9C                1       0       0             1             0             0
#> # ℹ 3 more variables: Y1.Scenario_3 <dbl>, Y2.Scenario_3 <dbl>,
#> #   Y3.Scenario_3 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: No need of if else. Ie `cumsum(value)*(value>0)`. 

Comment: @Onyambu yeah, `value != 0` works. I guess I should've had my morning coffee first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with

```
X = lapply(split.default(df[-1], gl(ncol(df[-1]) / 3, 3)), 
           \(x) t(apply(x, 1, cumsum))) |>
  do.call(cbind, args = _)
df[-1] = ifelse(df[-1] == 0, 0, X)
```

which is a *split-apply-combine* approach incorporating `cumsum` rowwisely (`MARGIN = 1` in `apply()`).

---

I recently saw a beautiful approach (as `ifelse()` alternative) to conditionally replace values of a data frame/matrix with values of another (same dimension), but cannot remember.

Answer (score 1):

I found a correct way for the function to not overwrite the cell value with a row-wise `cumsum` whenever there is a *0* in a cell, and continue calculating the cumulative until it hits Y1 again:

```
cumsum_w_reset <- function(df) {
      # Convert columns that need to be summed to numeric
      # this adds forced NA writing issue in the Rating column. Instead, subset df[-1] in the "Apply" row.
        #df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) if(!is.numeric(x)) as.numeric(as.character(x)) else x)
    
      # Apply the cumulative sum row-wise with resets
      t(apply(df, 1, function(row) {
        # Initialize the running sum
        running_sum <- 0
        # Initialize the flag to track if we should start summing
        start_sum <- FALSE
    
        # Iterate over each element of the row
        for (i in seq_along(row)) {
          # Check if the current column is a reset point
          if (grepl("^Y1", names(df)[i])) {
            running_sum <- row[i] # Set the running sum to the current value
            start_sum <- TRUE # Start summing from this point
          } else if (start_sum && row[i] != 0) {
            # Add the current value to the running sum if it's not 0
            running_sum <- running_sum + row[i]
            row[i] <- running_sum # Update the row with the new value
          }
          # If the value is 0, do not add to running_sum and do not update the value of the cell
        }
        return(row)
      }))
    }
    
    # Apply the function to the numeric columns of the dataframe
    #df[-1] <- cumsum_w_reset(df[-1])
    df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)] <-  cumsum_w_reset(df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)])
```